# how to set HTML class in email_field_tag in rails 4.1

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have:

```
<%= email_field_tag(:email, class:"loginTextbox", :size=>'100x100') %>`
```

I want to set `loginTextbox` class for this textbox but it has no effect at all.

How do I set a class?

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= email_field_tag(:email, '', class: 'loginTextbox', size: '100x100' %>
```

The second parameter of this helper is `value`. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/email_field_tag

If you are going to use `form_for`, you don't need to set second parameter.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'loginTextbox', size: '100x100' %>
<% end %>
```

In this case, email input will be filled with `@user.email`. If `@user` is new record, it has blank value.

Comment: still class is not working for email_field_tag.Is there any helper method to use.